# When comparing two list of IP addresses with bash, duplicate lines are printed

Tags: bash, shell, line, ip-address

I am trying to write a function that compares values in 2 files.
I have a logfile from which I have extracted unique IP addresses.
I have another file that has a list of domains in them which are "bad domians".
The objective is to print the list of IP addresses and also compare with the bad domains list and if a match is found, we need to prefix "bad address".

Conceptually, I can save the IP result to a file, and the domain result to a variable, use the while read loop on the IP file, a for loop on the domain variable and use grep to see if a pattern is found. If yes, add the prefix, else print normally. Yes, seems a bit time consuming but that is the idea.

```sh
list=`dig +short -f dns.blacklist.txt`
awk '{ print $1 }' $logfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' >> response
 
while read -r listed
do
    
    for x in $list
    do  
        if [ "$(echo $listed | grep -F $x )" ]; then 
        echo $listed "*bad domain!*"
        else
        #echo $listed
        fi
    done
done < response | uniq
```

It does find the bad IP and adds the prefix, problem is, it creates a duplicate.

What it should be

```
213.64.237.230 2438
213.64.225.123 1202 *bad domain!*
213.64.141.89 731
213.64.214.124 480
.
.
.
```

What it shows

```
213.64.237.230 2438
213.64.225.123 1202
213.64.225.123 1202 *bad domain!*
213.64.225.123 1202
213.64.141.89 731
213.64.214.124 480
.
.
.
```

I fail to see why a duplicate is being made. If I remove the else condition and push the normal print to after, it still prints the IP below while it shouldnt.

Do note that the results are being piped to the uniq command.

I need a hint on where I am wrong and how I can mitigate this error.

Comment: for file text processing make use of awk , while loop is not preferable

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not have access to your logfile or your dns.blacklist.txt files. I created dummy files using some of the ip addresses you listed.  I refactored your loops and your if check and was able to solve your duplicate output issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

# used instead of your list=`dig +short -f dns.blacklist.txt`
bad=/tmp/bad.txt

# used instead of your logfile parsing/sorting/ etc...
all=/tmp/all.txt


# read blacklisted ips into a bash variable
list=$(<${bad})

# for each ip parsed from your logfile count number of times
# it is found in blacklisted ips, if greater than 0 then flag
# as a bad domain

while read -r listed
do
    if [[ $(grep -c "${listed}" <<<${list}) -gt 0 ]]; then
            echo "${listed} *bad domain!*"
    else
            echo "${listed}"
    fi
done <${all}
```

Contents of bad.txt:

```
213.64.225.123 1202
```

Contents of all.txt:

```
213.64.237.230 2438
213.64.225.123 1202
213.64.141.89 731
213.64.214.124 480
```

Example output:

```
$ ./script.sh 
213.64.237.230 2438
213.64.225.123 1202 *bad domain!*
213.64.141.89 731
213.64.214.124 480
```